# PHP returns "permission denied". Possible ownership issue?

Tags: permissions, php, nginx, vps, ownership

**As an update.** I just figured that it works okay for one level. For example, mkdir('/var/www/laravel/storage/first', 777, true) but doesn't work when there are multiple levels like mkdir('/var/www/laravel/storage/first/second/third', 777, true) And it seems wrong, doesn't it? Because the 'recursive' parameter is set to `true`.

**Another important update.** `mkdir` simply fails to create folders with 777. It first creates one parent folder with `dr----x--t` and can't create children. I suspect some php config option or `umask`, I don't know. Looking into it.

---

The issue is that PHP returns "Permission denied" when I'm trying to create a folder (e.g. `/var/www/laravel/storage/new/directory/name`) even if I set all permissions to 777.

My setup is on DO's droplet, Ubuntu 18. It's Laravel website located at `/var/www/laravel` and served by nginx.

I've run `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

The output of `ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep` is:

```
root      2710  0.0  0.0 141284  1576 ?        Ss   14:04   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  2712  0.0  0.0 143584  7636 ?        S    14:04   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2714  0.0  0.0 143584  6368 ?        S    14:04   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2715  0.0  0.0 143584  6368 ?        S    14:04   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2716  0.0  0.0 143584  6368 ?        S    14:04   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

And here you can see the owner:

```
drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:26 ./
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 17:45 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    106 Mar  4 14:16 .babelrc
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    234 Mar  4 14:16 .editorconfig
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    651 Mar  4 14:16 .env.example
drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  7 13:44 .git/
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    111 Mar  4 14:16 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    129 Mar  4 14:16 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x 21 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  7 13:44 app/
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   1686 Mar  4 14:16 artisan
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:16 bootstrap/
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   1573 Mar  4 14:16 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 185669 Mar  4 14:27 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  5 16:31 config/
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:16 database/
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    597 Mar  4 14:16 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   1134 Mar  4 14:16 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  6 15:52 public/
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:16 resources/
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:16 routes/
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    563 Mar  4 14:16 server.php
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  7 12:52 storage/
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:16 tests/
drwxrwxr-x 46 www-data www-data   4096 Mar  4 14:27 vendor/
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    716 Mar  4 14:16 webpack.config.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    549 Mar  4 14:16 webpack.mix.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   1630 Mar  4 14:16 yarn-error.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 176590 Mar  4 14:16 yarn.lock
```

Permissions were set like so:

```
find /var/www/laravel/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/laravel/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

SELinux doesn't seem to be installed. `getenforce` command returns installation suggestion.

What else needs to be checked?

**UPDATE 1**

Permissions for the target forlder:

```
cd /var/www/laravel/storage
ll
```

Output:

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  7 12:52 ./
drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  4 14:26 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  4 14:16 app/
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  7 12:52 f/
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  4 14:16 framework/
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  4 15:18 logs/
```

**UPDATE 2**

The PHP's `exec('whoami')` returns 'www-data'

**UPDATE 3**

For folder creating in PHP I use `mkdir($pathInfo['dirname'], 777, true)` And path is absolute.

Comment: Where do you try to create a folder?

Comment: Under `storage`. So full path is `/var/www/laravel/storage/new/directory/name`

Comment: In order to create a directory a process needs write permission for the containing directory.

Comment: But as I can see it, the www-data has full permissions for the /var/www and below

Comment: Could you show the target dir perms and the php code used. Full path or relative path? Think about php.ini config too. And please verify the php user with `<?php echo ``whoami``; ?>`

Comment: @cmak.fr I've updated the question, can you please clarify what should I do about php.ini ?

Comment: i think about wrong interpretation of (eventual) relative path

Comment: If this is being run from a web server there is probably some sort of "chroot" in place. I haven't review this, but double-check that the path is server-relative. i.e., the web server may see /var/fnord/whatever as /.

Comment: I just figured that it works okay for one level. For example, `mkdir('/var/www/laravel/storage/first', 777, true)` but doesn't work when there are multiple levels like `mkdir('/var/www/laravel/storage/first/second/third', 777, true)`

And it seems wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php Are you using the recursive method to create nested structures? Make sure you read the notes, as chmod is affected with recursive.

Comment: @jdv yes, it's recursive. I've just found out that `mkdir` fails to create folders with 777, that's the root issue here.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to help, but the very top note on that page shows the same problem and a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165183/apache-permissions-php-file-create-mkdir-fail/5165435#5165435 could help